# Restsharp returning myobject as null when deserializing XML

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm working with the plex status API and I cannot get my objects to load.

Here are my rest client methods:

```
private static List<RestClient> GetRestClients()
    {
        var clientList = new List<RestClient>();

        foreach (PlexUrl pu in DatabaseHelper.GetPlexUrls())
        {
            var client = new RestClient();
            client.AddHandler("application/xml", new DotNetXmlDeserializer());
            client.BaseUrl = pu.Url;
            clientList.Add(client);
        }

        return clientList;
    }

    private static RestRequest GetRequest()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.Resource = "status/sessions";
        request.AddHeader(Constants.PLEX_TOKEN_PREFIX, Cache.Get<string>(Constants.PLEX_USER_TOKEN));

        return request;
    }

    public static List<MediaContainer> GetSessions()
    {
        var sessions = new List<MediaContainer>();

        foreach (var client in GetRestClients())
        {
            var response = client.Execute<MediaContainer>(GetRequest());

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.ErrorMessage))
            {
                Logger.LogError(response.ErrorMessage);

                if (Properties.Settings.Default.NotifyErrors)
                    MainWindow.TrayIcon.ShowBalloonTip("Error Connecting to PMS", string.Format("There was an error connecting to {0}.", client.BaseUrl), Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.BalloonIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                sessions.Add(response.Data);
            }
        }

        return sessions;
    }
```

Here is an example of the XML, The media container can contain multiple videos.

```
<MediaContainer size="1">
    <Video addedAt="1387660866" art="/library/metadata/696/art/1387660904" contentRating="R" duration="7607858" guid="com.plexapp.agents.themoviedb://87421?lang=en" key="/library/metadata/696" librarySectionID="1" originallyAvailableAt="2013-09-06" rating="6.0999999046325701" ratingKey="696" sessionKey="1" studio="Universal Pictures" summary="Betrayed by his own kind and left for dead on a desolate planet, Riddick fights for survival against alien predators and becomes more powerful and dangerous than ever before. Soon bounty hunters from throughout the galaxy descend on Riddick only to find themselves pawns in his greater scheme for revenge. With his enemies right where he wants them, Riddick unleashes a vicious attack of vengeance before returning to his home planet of Furya to save it from destruction." tagline="Survival Is His Revenge" thumb="/library/metadata/696/thumb/1387660904" title="Riddick" type="movie" updatedAt="1387660904" viewOffset="24922" year="2013">
        <Media aspectRatio="2.35" audioChannels="6" audioCodec="ac3" bitrate="4346" container="mkv" duration="7607858" height="796" id="652" videoCodec="h264" videoFrameRate="24p" videoResolution="1080" width="1916">
            <Part container="mkv" duration="7607858" file="/home/jim/Movies/Riddick (2013).mkv" id="652" key="/library/parts/652/file.mkv" size="4132905434">
                <Stream bitDepth="8" bitrate="3875" cabac="1" chromaSubsampling="4:2:0" codec="h264" codecID="V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC" colorSpace="yuv" duration="7607858" frameRate="23.976" frameRateMode="cfr" hasScalingMatrix="0" height="796" id="3677" index="0" language="English" languageCode="eng" level="40" profile="high" refFrames="5" scanType="progressive" streamType="1" title="" width="1916"/>
                <Stream bitDepth="16" bitrate="384" bitrateMode="cbr" channels="6" codec="ac3" codecID="A_AC3" dialogNorm="-27" duration="7607840" id="3678" index="1" language="English" languageCode="eng" samplingRate="48000" selected="1" streamType="2" title=""/>
            </Part>
        </Media>
        <Genre id="218" tag="Action"/>
        <Genre id="247" tag="Science Fiction"/>
        <Genre id="108" tag="Thriller"/>
        <Writer id="4080" tag="David Twohy"/>
        <Director id="4078" tag="David Twohy"/>
        <Producer id="6820" tag="Ted Field"/>
        <Producer id="4020" tag="Vin Diesel"/>
        <Producer id="6821" tag="Samantha Vincent"/>
        <Country id="71" tag="USA"/>
        <Role id="660" role="Riddick" tag="Vin Diesel" thumb="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/qwyfzMKIhxJ7ols66FgEf7eGdcI.jpg"/>
        <Role id="1054" role="Lord Vaako" tag="Karl Urban" thumb="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/tHYOUO33K7iaDw8nXyqRvDIkVuM.jpg"/>
        <Role id="6811" role="Dahl" tag="Katee Sackhoff" thumb="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/8NcZJxNRSxP2QegcWeX8WDnFlSs.jpg"/>
        <Role id="6812" role="Santana" tag="Jordi Moll&#xE0;" thumb="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/A648UpxxLlgdqziafgSCAVaR0Sc.jpg"/>
        <Role id="6813" role="Moss" tag="Bokeem Woodbine" thumb="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/5jxJLgIsEsKwsHSLVjNvMZzs1Mm.jpg"/>
        <Role id="6814" role="Luna" tag="Nolan Gerard Funk" thumb="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/an3qC0DTKiyzLs76Xw9t9crQfN5.jpg"/>
        <Role id="6815" role="Nunez" tag="Noah Danby" thumb="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/l6soX1Mb6V2QWwxrMjTVEaaaPB2.jpg"/>
        <Role id="6816" role="Rubio" tag="Neil Napier"/>
        <Role id="6817" role="" tag="Keri Hilson" thumb="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/bmrHsGOx35pcYKXjn1aEL7sb5Rd.jpg"/>
        <Role id="6818" role="Diaz" tag="Dave Bautista" thumb="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/gtb1sMCmZjAeF0lSdEWLjFsSvmr.jpg"/>
        <Role id="6819" role="Boss Johns" tag="Matthew Nable"/>
        <Collection id="4093" tag="The Chronicles of Riddick"/>
        <User id="1" thumb="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/57ddfffd0c28b16997abce76964b5c03?d=404" title="JBurlison@Gmail.com"/>
        <Player machineIdentifier="4f44996d-2fb4-4fcf-9ba4-4b3ab360ed27" platform="Android" state="playing" title="My SM-N900P"/>
        <TranscodeSession key="4f44996d-2fb4-4fcf-9ba4-4b3ab360ed27" throttled="0" progress="0.40000000596046448" speed="0.5" duration="7607000" videoDecision="transcode" audioDecision="transcode" protocol="hls" container="mpegts" videoCodec="h264" audioCodec="aac" audioChannels="2" width="1280" height="532"/>
    </Video>
</MediaContainer>
```

and my Objects: 
https://gist.github.com/JBurlison/8469403

I do deserialize simpler XML into objects successfully with other methods.

I debug through it and it seems to be trying to load The Video Object with the Media Tag instead of the Video Tag. I believe this is a bug, but I wanted to ask just in case I did something glaringly wrong.